# Upload Video to twitvid and get the link

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am doing a java application that uploads a video to twitvid and gets back the link of the video and post that to twitter.But I cant find any good example of uploading video to twitvid. The documentation at http://twitvid.pbworks.com/w/page/22556295/FrontPage is also confusing and no examples are given. Can anybody share an example or good documentation on this? The libraries are here at http://twitvid.pbworks.com/w/page/22556292/Client%20Libraries

Comment: For future reference, you should post the code you're working with and where you think it's going wrong.  I know that you may not know where to start, but people are unlikely to help you out if they don't see some effort on your part.

Comment: @user1429322 Did you find the solution? if yes please let me know as i am also want to upload video. I used twitvid java library but it is too old and unable to find the new one. And using Rest Api I dont know how to get Token then upload video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
Obviously, you'll need to import the necessary libraries, if you're using eclipse, it'll tell you what you need to import.

```
URL url = new URL("http://im.twitvid.com/api/uploadAndPost");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");

OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();

TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("filename.xml");
StreamSource source = new StreamSource(fileReader);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(os);
transformer.transform(source, result);

os.flush();
connection.getResponseCode();
connection.disconnect();
```

Where filename.xml will look something like this (from http://twitvid.pbworks.com/w/page/22556308/Twitvid%20API%20Method%3A%20uploadandpost):

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

     <rsp status='ok'>

           <status_id>1111</status_id>

           <user_id>TwitUsername</user_id>

           <media_id>3GS34</media_id>

           <media_url>http://twitvid.com/3GS34</media_url>

           <message>This is my tweet!</message>

           <geo_latitude>57.64911</geo_latitude>

           <geo_longitude>10.40744</geo_longitude>

      </rsp>
```

Where you'd need to replace the values in the .xml with the values that are relevant to you.  The twitvid page that I linked describes what should go in all the fields above.  Good luck, hope that helps.

Edit: a lot of those fields are optional, for example, you probably don't need geo_latitude/longitude.  That page should explain everything.  I know it may seem confusing, but try to work with it.  Hopefully the code above will solve your problems.

Comment: Thanks Steve...I will try this.But can you please explain the process so that I could do the flow correctly? If I am not wrong what I understood so far is it takes the parameters in filename.xml to post the tweet.But where should I send the video? Ill post the full source once I make it run.

Comment: Basically, their API has it set up such that when you send an HTTP POST to http://im.twitvid.com/api/uploadAndPost, it automatically does what you want it to do (based off your description).  The java code merely sends an HTTP POST.  What they accept in that post is an .xml or json.

Comment: In the xml, "twitvid.com/3GS34"; is the location of the video. In the java file, URL url = new URL("http://im.twitvid.com/api/uploadAndPost"); this address if where you're actually sending your HTTP POST to. I'd post something more detailed, but the stuff that I didn't post is really up to you. This should work just fine. If it doesn't you can use this as a basis and submit another post that is more refined. Could you please upvote and/or accept my answer. Thanks!

Comment: So, I understand that basically, 1: You connect with twitter, 2: you send in json or xml the stuff written in the API description, 3: Then you send the video as a multipart file.

Comment: @LéonPelletier, basically.

Comment: (But the answer makes no sense.) Why sending a file instead of direct UTF data. And more obvious, this is the response. There are some clues about it: "rsp", "status OK", and the fact that this is clearly the result as stated in the twitvid infos, and not the request.

Comment: Huh?  In the example, the video url was passed.